# How Do I download all the images generated from canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making new drawings on canvas and in particular time, it saves the image of the canvas by `canvas.toDataURL()`.

Following is the code i am using to save urls of the images in an array:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var images = [];
function foo(){
    /* do my work */;
    images.push(canvas.toDataURL());
    /* clearing canvas to get new image and draw again on canvas */ 
}
```

Now the function `foo()` will be called many times but after an event, it will stop and now I need to download all of the images stored in `images[]` by zipping all of the images to a zip file. Is it even possible to do that?

Comment: I think you will need a zip library to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library. See example:

```
var zip = new JSZip();
var img = zip.folder("images");
img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});
var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
saveAs(content, "example.zip");
```

You need to use `img.file()` method in loop for create multiple images (don't forget about different names of files).

Comment: This didn't work, but replaced
 `img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});` 
with : 
`img.src.substr(img.src.indexOf(',')+1)`.

And this worked, but didn't understand what this does?

Comment: what's `saveAs`?

Comment: @Onheiron Another library... FileSaver.js